# Move Json Object From One Site To Another

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, webforms

I have two project in asp.net webforms with different url. I need to move c# object from one to the other. I tried to serialize it to JSON with `JavaScriptSerializer` and move it as parameter in the url, but I don't want the client would see the json

```
A a = new A()
{
    val = 1,
    val1 = "very long string"
};

var jsonSerialiser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
string data = jsonSerialiser.Serialize(a);
Response.Redirect(service.RedirectToCheckout("http://localhost:44316/PageOnOtherSite.aspx?data=" + data));
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Make a post request to the other app

Comment: Thanks for your responding, do you have any code example for that?

Answer (score 1):

simple post request using `HttpClient`

```
using(var client = new HttpClient())
{     
    response = await httpClient.PostAsync(uri, new StringContent(data));
{
```